# is it possible to authenticate to game center without an internet connection?

Tags: ios, wifi, game-center

is it possible to authenticate to game center without an internet connection?

I assumed if I didn't have internet that game center would use my 'data plan' to transmit information, however I am finding that if my iPhone is not connected to a wifi that I can't authenticate to the game center.

Has anyone else experienced this?
Is it a matter of 'iPhone settings'. I don't find an option under 'game center' to 'use data plan' when no internet is available.

Many thanks

Comment: When you say internet connection, do you mean Wifi (as opposed to cellular data network)?

Comment: Yes. This is what I mean

Comment: I have just tried it with iOS 7.1: turned off Wifi, logged out from Game Center under settings, started GameCenter-enabled app; it asks for password and displays the "Welcome back ..." banner as normal with Game Center.

Comment: Nice. I just tried outside my house and it worked too. I must have bad data service in my house and at my friends house

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need good service. Some houses/apartments just don't get good data service to log in.